# Merging two Zend_Config_Ini instances overwrites arrays defined in first object

Tags: zend-framework, merge, zend-config

Given two *.ini files:

**one.ini**

```
[production]
someArray[] = 'one'
someArray[] = 'two'
someArray[] = 'three'

[development : production]
```

**two.ini**

```
[production]
someArray[] = 'four'

[development : production]
```

**Load both *.ini files as Zend_Config_Ini instances**

```
$one = new Zend_Config_Ini(
    APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/one.ini",
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    array('allowModifications' => true)
);

$two = new Zend_Config_Ini(
    APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/two.ini",
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    array('allowModifications' => true)
);

$one->merge($two);
print_r($one->toArray());
```

**Output after merge:**

```
Array
(
    [someArray] => Array
        (
            [0] => four
            [1] => two
            [2] => three
        )

)
```

**Is it possible to merge the arrays in a way that the output would be like the example below?**

I know it can be done by defining numerical indices on the arrays in each *.ini file, but I would like to avoid this, if possible.

```
//Ideal merge results

Array
(
    [someArray] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
            [1] => two
            [2] => three
            [3] => four
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new = new Zend_Config(array_merge_recursive($one->toArray(), $two->toArray()));
var_dump($new->toArray());
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of these two solutions :

```
$config = new Zend_Config($two->asArray() + $one->asArray()); 
var_dump($config->asArray());
```

or

```
$config = new Zend_Config(array_merge($one->asArray(),  $two->asArray()));  

var_dump($config->asArray());
```

Comment: Neither of these work for me. I should have stated I am using ZF version 1.11. `asArray()` is not an available method. Assuming you meant `toArray()`, this does not work either.